# Mostrar datos de un RecyclerView solo con la fecha actual

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, recyclerview

Buenos días me encuentro trabajando en un `RecyclerView` que obtiene los reportes de pedidos y pues en este caso la pregunta es bastante sencilla, como podría obtener los datos en el `RecyclerView` solo de la fecha de ahora por ejemplo si este día 25-05-21 se hicieron 10 pedidos que se muestren solo esos 10 si mañana no se hicieron pedidos que el `ReyclerView` aparezca vacío y así sucesivamente conforme avanzan los días, sin mas explicare mi avance hasta el momento.

En primer lugar no se si el código se debería desarrollar en la consulta PHP o en Android Studio o hacer un cambio en MySQL por eso mostrare todos los pasos.

Aquí tengo mi consulta **PHP** nada del otro mundo solo hago un `select` a todos los campos de la tabla.

```
<?php

require "conn.php";

$sql = "select * from fac_prefactura";

 $query = $mysqli->query($sql);

$datos = array();

while($resultado = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $datos[] = $resultado;
  }

echo json_encode(array("Reporte" => $datos));

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Nos vamos a Android Studio y comienzo creando mi adaptador.

```
public class AdaptadorReportes extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorReportes.ReportesViewHolder> {

Context cContext;
public static List<Reportes> listaReportes;

public AdaptadorReportes(Context cContext, List<Reportes> listaReportes) {

    this.cContext = cContext;
    AdaptadorReportes.listaReportes = listaReportes;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ReportesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_rv_reportes, viewGroup, false);
    return new ReportesViewHolder(v);

}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReportesViewHolder reportesViewHolder, int posicion) {

    reportesViewHolder.tvFecha.setText(listaReportes.get(posicion).getFecha());
    reportesViewHolder.tvPedido.setText(Integer.toString(listaReportes.get(posicion).getPedido()));
    reportesViewHolder.tvTotal.setText(Double.toString(listaReportes.get(posicion).getTotal()));

    reportesViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {

    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaReportes.size();
}

public static class ReportesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView tvFecha, tvPedido, tvTotal;

    public ReportesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

    tvFecha = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFecha);
    tvPedido = itemView.findViewById(R.id.numeroPedido);
    tvTotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.montoTotal);

    }
}
}
```

Y por ultimo mi fragmento donde dibujo el recycler con todos los datos.

```
public class FragmentReportes extends Fragment {

RecyclerView rvLista;
ArrayList<Reportes> reportes;
AdaptadorReportes adaptador;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    obtenerReportes();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vista =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reportes, container, false);

    reportes = new ArrayList<>();
    rvLista = vista.findViewById(R.id.rvListaReportes);

    rvLista.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    return vista;
}

public void obtenerReportes() {

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Por favor espera...");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

    String URL_REPORTES = "http://pedidoslab.6te.net/consultas/obtenerReporte.php";

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_REPORTES,

            response -> {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Reporte");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        reportes.add(
                                new Reportes(

                                        jsonObject1.getString("fecha_creo"),
                                        jsonObject1.getInt("id_prefactura"),
                                        jsonObject1.getDouble("monto")));
                    }

                    adaptador = new AdaptadorReportes(getContext(), reportes);
                    rvLista.setAdapter(adaptador);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }, Throwable::printStackTrace
    ) {
    };

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            CatFragment.MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

}
```

Sinceramente a pesar de que he investigado al respecto no encuentro una respuesta en especifico, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, me gustaría compartir mas código pero eso es todo lo que tengo, de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es obtener solo los pedidos del día lo ideal es en tu consulta

```
$sql = "select * from fac_prefactura";
```

Agregar un where

```
$sql = "select * from fac_prefactura where columnaFecha = getdate()";
```

Aunque lo ideal seria que la fecha fuera un parametro de entrada o filtraras por rango

Luego de tu app cuando llamas al servicio

```
String URL_REPORTES = "http://pedidoslab.6te.net/consultas/obtenerReporte.php";
```

Le envie el parametro de entrada que seria la fecha

No use ningun compilador perdon si hay errores de codigo pero esa es la idea

Comment: Excelente me ha funcionado a la perfeccion amigo he cambiado la consulta a como la dices tu a la siguiente $sql = "select * from fac_prefactura where fecha_creo BETWEEN CURDATE() and CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY"; y ya ha quedado funcionando muy bien, Gracias!